# How to reset the default Windows command line after installing Cygwin?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, cygwin, control-panel

I have installed cygwin into my Windows 8.1 and configured the settings in the advanced system (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables)

It has been long time since I made this configuration and I am not sure what I have configured exactly, but what I remember is that I have tried to make the windows terminal (cmd.exe) runs unix commands (cygwin) as the default rather than windows commands.  My best guest is that I played with the "Path" system variable; however, I do not see cygwin to be add as value in the Path variable (C:\ProgramData...\Scripts)

Now I want to use windows command not unix commands, Is there away to reset to the default options?

Comment: "I am not sure what I have configured exactly" we aren't sure either and we are not mind readers so we can't answer your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the default Windows command line in Unix"? Please [edit] your question so we know what happened and what you want.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question better.  I hope it helps now @BenN

Comment: `set | grep -i ComSpec`
`COMSPEC='C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe'`
It returns this!?

Comment: I am able to run Unix commands in cmd.exe.  It seems that cmd.exe is capable to run windows commands after as well as Unix command after installing cygwin.

Comment: may you try this in a new cmd instance? `set path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%`, then see if you can only use windows but not unix command?

Answer (score 0):

When you run SET from the command prompt, you'll see PATH as one of the variables. The order of execution will be based on the paths listed in order.

If you want to execute commands a specific executable, you may need to use the explicit path where the command exists. Alternatively, you can adjust the PATH order so that cmd.exe looks at a specific path before cygwin.